# phpword sombreado de línea completa de texto

Tags: php, style, phpword

Utilizo phpword para crear un documento pero cuando intento sombrear una línea completa de un título con lo siguiente...

```
$phpWord = new PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('marginLeft' => 850, 'marginRight' => 850, 'marginTop' => 640, 'marginBottom' => 1800));

$phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);

$phpWord->setDefaultFontName('newsgott');

$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 15, 'bold' => true, 'bgcolor' => 'f1f1f1', 'width' => 11905.51181102), array('marginLeft' => 15, 'marginRight' => 15, 'marginTop' => 40));

$section->addTitle($html['titulo']->getNombre(), 1);
```

pero solo me sombrea las letras y necesito que sombree la línea completa.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Sustituir:

```
$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 15, 'bold' => true, 'bgcolor' => 'f1f1f1', 'width' => 11905.51181102), array('marginLeft' => 15, 'marginRight' => 15, 'marginTop' => 40));
```

por:

```
$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 15, 'bold' => true), array('shading' => array('fill' => 'f1f1f1')));
```